# HEROKU: Logging in with another Heroku accnt and deploying fails my build

Tags: express, heroku, nodes, bcrypt

**UPDATE:**
I removed the warning by switching bcrypt versions V3 with V1.03. BUT now my passwords don't work. I assume it's because of the different hashing between both versions.

---

I created a personal Heroku account and uploaded my MERN project without a problem. I then created a 2nd Heroku accnt for work.

I then `heroku logout` and `heroku login` with the new account. I then tried uploading the same project with no changes, but keep getting

```
bcrypt@3.0.2 install /tmp/build_c823e78c1ca132209f395f59cc6e1071/node_modules/bcrypt
node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build

// lots of node-pre-gyp ERR! code before finishing with 

gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_c823e78c1ca132209f395f59cc6e1071/node_modules/bcrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v8.12.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.2 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.2 install script.
```

- Node v8.12.0
- NPM  6.4.1
- Git version 2.17.1 (Apple Git-112)
- macOS Mojave V 10.14

Comment: Are you targeting the same app on Heroku, or a different one?

Comment: @Chris different one, I run  heroku git:remote -a herokuURL when setting up the new Heroku Accnt

Comment: Do the [stacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#viewing-which-stack-your-app-is-using) of the two apps match?

Comment: @Chris no, two different stacks, and HEROKU urls are different, when i ran heroku stacks from CLI, i got these available stacks   
cedar-14
container
heroku-16
* heroku-18

Answer (score 0):

I use bcrypt 3.0.2 and ran into a similar issue today. Locally I am using Node version 10.11.0, but because I haven't specified it in the *package.json*, Heroku took a default Node version 8.XX.XX. I set it explicitly for Heroku as the same version as I use locally in my *package.json* file and then it worked.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "engines": {
    "node": "10.11.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
   ...
```

Comment: Nice, I got it to work by installing node-gyp, then I updated my bcrypt to v3.0.2